# Is there a way to create a GUI in Lua?

Tags: user-interface, graphics, lua

I am working on a Genetic Algorithm solution to TSP in Lua, and have reached a point where I need a better method of troubleshooting and checking results. The best way to do this would be with a GUI, but I can't seem to find anything about GUIs in Lua.

I've done some searching around Google, and haven't found anything built in to the language. I have found Toolkits such as the one found here:

http://lua-users.org/wiki/GraphicalUserInterfaceToolkits

However, I am new enough to Lua that I do not know how to properly use these. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are still shaky in Lua, I suggest to stick to the console for a while. GUI, whatever the language, is usually messy and unsatisfying for beginners.

If you already know some HTML and Javascript, consider using Lua with a web framework, and using the browser to control your program through a REST API:

- [Awesome-Lua#Web/Networking Platforms](https://github.com/LewisJEllis/awesome-lua#webnetworking-platforms)

Apart from that, I have yet to find a GUI framework that *feels right* for Lua. Almost everything is a thin wrapper around a C or C++ API and handles exactly like that. On the other hand, with the web and Electron on the rise there seems little need for it.

Comment: I do know some HTML and JS, but would appreciate any help in getting the API properly set up and using it if you know of any tutorials or anything

Comment: Depends on the toolkit you are mostly comfortable with. Most of LUA GUI wrappers are just that, wrappers to corresponding functions in GTK, WXWidgets or other toolkit. WX has a lot of manuals, samples and howto's, GTK has tons of code and tutorials so you just have to pick a toolkit and stick with it. If you expect WISYWIG editors for LUA... there is no such thing. Most of the coding is done in console or text editors and there are no VisualStudio or Freepascal like GUI builders. However i would recommend either WXLua or VCLua since they are mature, can be learned and work on many platforms.

Comment: @JordanLejman that is up to very personal preferences, for Lua I used the kepler stack before; OpenResty and Pegasus look way nicer though. On the JS side - Incidentally, there is also a library called [pegasus](https://github.com/typicode/pegasus), which is very suited for a hacky approach if you only need the xhr part - if you need any more on the JS side, I'd go Vue or React, or whatever framework you already know directly

Comment: I want to point to Lapis, a web framework for Lua and Moonscript. Given the popularity and relative simplicity of web interfaces, I think it's a great choice. [Reference](https://leafo.net/lapis/reference/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 4):

A few ideas:

But first, what platform are you on?

Are you constrained by platform? If not, I've done very exciting things directly on an iPad, in [Codea](https://codea.io). Pure Lua, built on OpenGL, so built-in API for graphics support.

Beyond that, you could probably use [Love2d](https://love2d.org/). It's meant for game dev, but you could probably adapt it to your needs. It's a Lua API, has graphics support, and is cross-platform. I don't know much about it (yet), so others could pipe in with their thoughts/opinions.

Comment: I'm on a PC using ZeroBrane Studio IDE. The project is more conceptual than practical so really only I will be using it.

Comment: PC - meaning Windows 10 on Intel/AMD?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 and Intel

Answer (score 1):

There's a new lua framework called Limekit. You can get a window showing with only 2 lines of code, plus it has a much friendlier/simplified API than most of these frameworks. It also supports material UI,dark and light mode too.

https://www.reddit.com/r/limekit/s/GTW4W1II7l
https://limekit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

[Redbean](https://redbean.dev/) is a *single-file distributable web server* which runs Lua; combined with the [fullmoon](https://github.com/pkulchenko/fullmoon/tree/master) framework, it makes it quite easy to build cross-platform apps with web gui.